# Como obter a data da próxima sexta-feira

Tags: php

Gostaria de informar que dia cai toda sexta que vem, como faço? Aí quando chegar na próxima sexta informa a outra sexta e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) permite gerar datas a partir de strings como "próxima sexta" (em inglês):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next Friday'));
```

[Veja funcionando](https://repl.it/repls/ScratchyStarryBlobfish).

Comment: kkkkk estou 2 dias tentando fazer isso com diversos código chegue a colocar todos os dias da semana e meses em variaveis para tentar solucionar mas quando troquei a data para testar em fevereiro que é até 28 ou 29 dava errado! Aí vem um abençoado igual você e resolve com apenas uma linha de código kkkkkkk muito obrigado amigo resolveu!